# support << operator in a macro

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to implement a macro which does the following:

```
#define report(s)   print(), throw std::runtime_error(s)
```

`print()` is a function that I always call to print some predefined stuff. `s` need to support:

```
report("abc"); // ok
report("abc"<<100); // == report("abc100")
```

**Apart from whatever print() outputs, Nothing else should be printed. The exception will be caught by the caller and printed there.**

I find it difficult to support << in the above macro.

P.S. **report() is a macro already used every where in my code base and I just want to change its behaviour. Calls like report("abc"<<100); have to be supported.** define it as a function and add ';' at the end doesn't look appropriate.

Comment: What should be the behaviour of this `<<` operator?

Comment: No reason here is given for using a macro in the first place. You could just have report be a function that calls print and then throws.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you expecting << to convert 100 to a string and append that to the "abc"? That's a stream mechanic, but you aren't dealing with streams here.

Comment: How do you expect `std::runtime_error("abc"<<100)` to be processed?

Comment: `#define report(s)   print(), throw std::runtime_error((std::stringstream{}<<s).to_string())`

Comment: "Doesn't look appropriate" does not cut it as a reason to use a macro and not a function. There are so, so many issues with macros... They are to be considered a last resort tool in C++.

Comment: @MooingDuck * `.str()`

Comment: @NirFriedman i think i am somehow convinced to use function now.

Comment: edited my question to clarify a bit more.

Comment: If you *insist* on using a macro (I think you should not), then *at least* wrap it in `do { /* stuff */ } while(false}` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following (untested!) code might be inspirational

```
#define report(Log) do { std::ostringstream _os; \
  _os << Log << std::flush; print(_os.str()); \
  throw std::runtime(_os.str()); } while(0)
```

and you might use it as `report("x=" << x)`;

BTW, you might even pass the source location using

```
#define report_at(Log,Fil,Lin)  do { std::ostringstream _os; \
  _os << Fil << ":" << Lin << ": " << Log << std::flush; \
  print(_os.str()); \
  throw std::runtime(_os.str()); } while(0)
```

<sup>(to lower probability of collision with `_os` you might even replace all its occurrences inside the brace with `_os##Lin` using preprocessor  [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html))</sup>

```
#define report_at_bis(Log,Fil,Lin) report_at(Log,Fil,Lin)

#define report(Log) report_at_bis(Log,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

and this shows one of the cases where a macro is really useful.

Comment: For Visual Studio, prefer `_os << Fil << '(' << Lin << ") : " << Log;`, because if that ends up in the output window, the IDE can detect it and likify it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OP should use `emacs` as his favorite source code editor, as I do.

Comment: As emacs doesn't linkify any particular format, my advice stands. My suggestion works the same or better on every IDE I know of.